# get data as an array using ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, post, send

I have a code that will get the data from the php file.
Here it is:

```
function getMods(){
    var init;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "init.php",
    data: { 'id': getID()},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
        {
            init = data;
        },
        async:false
    });
    return init;
}
```

Here is the php file:

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$value = "";
$init = array("Name","Owner","Admin1","Admin2","Admin3","Admin4");
for($i = 0; $i > 6;$i++){
$value[$i] = chatMods($init[$i],$id,$username,$password);
}
echo json_encode($value);
}
?>
```

Php file send data that is a string. I want to send a data that is an array of string. How can I do that?

Comment: what is the value of $init?

Comment: a string. example, "john"

Comment: I want to nake it an array like, "John" => owner, "John2" => user1, "john3" => user2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an array from your PHP, the best is to use json :

In your PHP file:

```
$data = array('hello', 'world');
echo json_encode($data);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",  
url: "init.php",
data: { 'id': getID(), 'Name': name },
cache: false,
success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    async:false
});
```

Comment: console.log(data); can be init = data[''];?

Comment: well you can do init = data as you did in your initial code. Now init will have an array as you wanted. Use console.log to check the value of init and see if that's what you want.

Comment: saying "something is wrong" won't help at all. include this in the very beginning of your file:
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

Comment: I got a values undefined.

Comment: well then you showed the wrong code, because your variable is called "value", not "values"

Comment: var mods = getMods();
console.log(mods); logged the values i want. When i try console.log(mods[0]), logged the value that is not right.

Comment: change the js file, for the function of getmods.

Comment: well, what does console.log(mods); print out ?

Comment: "&nbsp;John", "&nbsp;John1",... it is correct.. but console.log(mods[0]) print out '"'.

Comment: did you add dataType: "json" as I pasted in my JS sample ?